# Double zooming two sections of a Processing video

Tags: video, image-processing, processing, zooming

I am having a heck of a time trying to use translate(), scale(), mask() etc., in Processing to zoom two different sections of video from a camera.  I want the video areas shown by the "X" and "Y" in the first ascii image to fill each side, appearing as in the second.  Can anyone help?

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                              +
+                              +
+                              +
+ *   *                 *   *  +
+  * *                   * *   +
+   *                     *    +
+  * *                    *    +
+ *   *                   *    +
+                              +
+                              +
+                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+*          *      *          *+
+ *        *        *        * +
+  *      *          *      *  +
+   *    *            *    *   +
+    *  *              *  *    +
+     **                **     +
+    *  *               *      +
+   *    *              *      +
+  *      *             *      +
+ *        *            *      +
+*          *           *      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you want to scale from centre.
By default, the coordinate system' origin is at 0,0, the top left corner.

If you want to scale from the centre of the image, you first need to translate there then scale. After you've scaled from centre, you need to translate back to top left to render.

Here's a basic example:

```
PGraphics frame;

float scale = 1.0;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  //fake a camera/video frame to test with
  frame = createGraphics(width,height);
  frame.beginDraw();
  frame.textSize(700);
  frame.text("X",0,480);
  frame.text("Y",250,480);
  frame.endDraw();
}
void draw(){
  background(0);

  //move "transformation point" from top left corner to centre
  //by translating by half the frame size
  translate(frame.width/2,frame.height/2);
  //scale from centre
  scale(scale);
  //move coordinate system back to top left and draw the im
  image(frame,-frame.width/2,-frame.height/2);

}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) scale += 0.1;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) scale -= 0.1;
}
```

The `frame` variable is a placeholder what will be your camera/movie frame, so don't worry too much about what's going in `setup()`. The important parts are commented in `draw()`. Use the up/down arrow keys to change scale.

[image: xy scaled up]

[image: xy scaled down]

Note that this will affect other objects drawn after this image. If you want to isolate the scaling from centre just for the image, you can put the transformation within [pushMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html),[popMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) calls. These will isolate a coordinate system independent from the Processing's global coordinate system:

```
PGraphics frame;

float scale = 1.0;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  //fake a camera/video frame to test with
  frame = createGraphics(width,height);
  frame.beginDraw();
  frame.textSize(700);
  frame.text("X",0,480);
  frame.text("Y",250,480);
  frame.endDraw();
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  //isolate coordinate system
  pushMatrix();
    //move "transformation point" from top left corner to centre
    //by translating by half the frame size
    translate(frame.width/2,frame.height/2);
    //scale from centre
    scale(scale);
    //move coordinate system back to top left and draw the im
    image(frame,-frame.width/2,-frame.height/2);
  popMatrix();
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) scale += 0.1;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) scale -= 0.1;
}
```

For more details be sure to check out the [2D Transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/)

To get a better picture of how this works, here's a version that illustrates each coordinate transformation:

```
PGraphics frame;

float scale = 1.0;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  strokeWeight(3);
  //fake a camera/video frame to test with
  frame = createGraphics(width,height);
  frame.beginDraw();
  frame.textSize(700);
  frame.text("X",0,480);
  frame.text("Y",250,480);
  frame.endDraw();
}
void draw(){
  background(0);

  drawCoordinateSystem("Processing/global CS",100);

  //isolate coordinate system
  pushMatrix();
    //move "transformation point" from top left corner to centre
    //by translating by half the frame size
    translate(frame.width * .5,frame.height * .5);
    drawCoordinateSystem("translated to image centre",100);
    //scale from centre
    scale(scale);
    drawCoordinateSystem("scaled from image centre",100);
    //move coordinate system back to top left and draw the im
    pushMatrix();
    translate(-frame.width * .5,-frame.height * .5);
    drawCoordinateSystem("scaled back to image top/left",100);
    image(frame,0,0);
    popMatrix();
  popMatrix();
}
void drawCoordinateSystem(String label,float size){
  text(label,15,15);
  stroke(192,0,0);
  line(0,0,size,0);
  stroke(0,192,0);
  line(0,0,0,size);
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) scale += 0.1;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) scale -= 0.1;
}
```

[image: Coordinate System Visualisation]